# Seeking pattern of HTMl/CSS code to layout buttons at bottom of form

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've come across the need to display two buttons at the bottom of many forms, one being a Cancel and the other being a Submit.  As per the design specs I've received, they always need to be aligned to the right side, with a small gap between them.

I don't have much experience with Flexbox but would definitely like to use it.  Here's what I've come up with so far (with superfluous details stripped away) :

```html
<div style='display:flex; justify-content: flex-end'>
  <div>
    <button>Cancel</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button>Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

This works ... sort of ... though with no gap between the buttons.  It seems like a LOT of code for such a simple use case.  Might there be a simpler way to accomplish this?

Comment: You don't need flex-box for doing that. You can also use `float: right` instead. For the gap you need to use a `margin`.

Comment: No, don't use float right, or you'll open the Floatdora's box. Stick to flex.

Comment: `<div style='display:flex; justify-content: flex-end'><button>Cancel</button>&nbsp;<button>Submit</button></div>`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan What's the disadvantage of float in that simple case?

Comment: @Paul no experience with floats? Assign a background color to a parent, float the child elements. Do you see any parent background color? https://jsfiddle.net/bcx02yje/ And that's just the beginning...

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Interesting. Even though I did some css stuff for several years I never ran into bigger issues with floats. Even though I do prefer flex in trickier cases and more and more also in simpler cases, since they are just kind of nice and 'flexible'. I will check that out. Thanks for pointing that out! I'm actually surprised I've never noticed the background issue.

Comment: @Paul talking about bad CSS stuff, I seriously don't remember the last time I used `float` or `!important` for that matter...

Answer (score 1):

Use a margin to separate the two buttons. Flexbox works well for the general layout.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
 
.container button:first-child {
  margin-right: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <button>Cancel</button>
  <button>Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: @robert - Worth noticing that `.container` is a too common selector. Create a new one for that specific parent, like i.e: `class="form-footer"` or something.

Comment: @robert - Also, `<button>Cancel</button>` should be `<button type="button">Cancel</button>` otherwise it will act just like the Submit one.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan That depends on the codebase; if you are using something like CSS Modules, that class name could be okay. But class names should definitely be accounted for!

Answer (score 0):

No need for flexbox or any of the extra `div` markup. Keep it simple, just use `text-align` and assign a margin.

```css
.wrap {
  text-align: right;
}

.wrap button {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <button>Cancel</button>
    <button>Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: the margin won't be exactly 10px due to whitespace

Comment: @TemaniAfif The OP has not specified that they need a pixel-perfect amount of whitespace.

Comment: even if it's not the case, the OP (or anyone seeing this question) need to know that the real space is not 10px that's why I added my comment. This doesn't mean your answer is wrong or the approach is bad.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS grid:

```css
.buttons {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-gap: 5px; /* your gap here */
  justify-content: flex-end
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons" >
  <button>Cancel</button>
  <button>Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, amazing responses!!!  I now need to carefully go through all of them.  Thank you, everyone!!!

Comment: I like your Grid approach.  Suppose I wanted to have a 3rd button off to the far left?  How would I do that?

Comment: I think I figured it out.  I kept your parent `div` and then added two child `div`'s, one for the left aligned button(s) and one for the right aligned button(s).  Here's my basic CSS:

```buttons: {
  display: 'grid',
  gridAutoFlow: 'column',
},
buttonsLeft: {
  display: 'grid',
  gridAutoFlow: 'column',
  gridGap: '15px',
  justifySelf: 'start',
},
buttonsRight: {
  display: 'grid',
  gridAutoFlow: 'column',
  gridGap: '15px',
  justifySelf: 'end'
}```

Comment: @robertwerner_sf no need extra div, you do like this: https://jsfiddle.net/tdb2mn4e/